# How openmp works when using fewer threads than have

Tags: c++, openmp

My computer has 16 cores. 
My program is like the following:

```
omp_set_num_threads(16);
....
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
for(int i =1; i<=2; ++i)
{
 \\time consuming operations
 }
```

Which is more efficient `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)` or `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(16)`? Or they are the same, since it is shared memory? Pay attention to the fact that my loop iterations are smaller than 16.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from benchmarking this yourself?

Comment: I'm not really sure but isn't `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)` saying run the below code for `num_threads` in parallel? I don't believe loop iteration count comes into play.

Comment: Should note aswell that you may never have access to all 16 hardware threads, and could potentially get context switched off any.

Comment: 14 of the 16 threads will be assigned no iteration of the for loop. There may be some negligible difference in spawning and managing 16 rather than 2 threads, but the difference should be marginal if the content of the loop is indeed a time consuming task

Answer (score 1):

Omit any manual specification such as `omp_set_num_threads` or `num_threads` and let the implementation figure it out.

Practically, it should make no noticeable difference either way.

`omp_set_num_threads` is completely redundant, as it only applies to subsequent
parallel regions that do not specify a `num_threads` clause. So if you feel like you must, use either `omp_set_num_threads` or a `num_threads` clause as it is just confusing to the reader.

It is conceivable that `num_threads(2)`, however specified, is better. It has a smaller initialization overhead for creating less threads. That probably doesn't matter. There is a theoretical argument the excessive threads which have no work to do could drain shared resources while waiting (shared cores with hyperthreading, powercap) - still it should not matter because OpenMP implementations don't do indefinite busy waiting.

On the other hand, manually specifying `num_threads(2)` creates a redundancy. What if your loop changes to three iterations, but you forget? You waste performance. Same goes for "*I put `num_threads(X)` because I have `X` cores*", kind of code.

Again, just omit it. However, measure your application regularly. If you have specific indication of possibly related performance issues - reevaluate the choice based on specific actionable measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Your OpenMP pragma is not correct, it should be:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
```

Please look [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/32-openmp-traps-for-c-developers#IDARNQDC) for explanations - and this whole article is very good for learning the OpenMP.

Comment: Thanks for the remainder. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `for`-loop isn't really a `for`-loop at all: you only have two iterations. A better solution might be to use *OpenMP* `sections`:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    {
        // Time-consuming operations
    }
    #pragma omp section 
    {
        // Other independent time-consuming operations
    }
}
```

Comment: By what metric would this be a better solution? Why is a `for` loop with two (or any fixed number of iterations greater than 1) *not really a `for` loop*?

Comment: I said it _might_ be a better solution. If someone is using a `for` loop with just two iterations, I strongly suspect they might have an `if-else` on the iteration variable inside the loop and just don't know about `sections` for some reason, so they're doing it the way they know about. In this case, maybe it's semantically correct for it to be a `for` loop, and maybe it's not. I don't know (and neither do you), but two iterations in an `omp for` has a "code smell" that suggests `sections` might be better, if not for the OP, then for others who might read this.